# Shortcut for inserting matching \end{something} in VIM

Tags: vim, auto-completion, vim-latex

I remember some time ago I always used a shortcut in VIM that allowed me to type this (`<X>` is indication of the location of the cursor):

```
... rest of document ...

\begin{<ENVIRONMENT>}
  some text
  more text
<X>

... document continues ....
```

and then I would key in some shortcut at the location of `<X>` and the matching `\end{<ENVIRONMENT>}` would be inserted:

```
... rest of document ...

\begin{<ENVIRONMENT>}
  some text
  more text
\end{<ENVIRONMENT>}

... document continues ....
```

Here, of course, `<ENVIRONMENT>` can be anything, like `align` or `itemize`.

I know about VIM's `<C-x> + <C-p>`, `<C-x + <C-n>` and `<C-x> + <C-o>`. The last one works very well for closing HTML tags, but it doesn't work in LaTeX.

I forgot what it was and I hope someone here knows it. It might have been a plugin but I don't think so. If anyone can tell me what it is, I will be forever grateful.

EDIT:
Of course I *am* using LaTeX-Suite (or vim-latex, wish they'd stick to a name).

Comment: I'm not referring to that, but nice to know, it's basically as useful as what I'm looking for, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of the [closeb](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=226)  script.

Comment: Tested the closeb script, works very well.

Answer (score 28):

When using [VimTeX](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex), you can type `]]` in insert mode to close the current environment.

Answer (score 12):

Something that is pretty much as useful is to type `nameofenvironment` then <kbd>F5</kbd> which gives

```
\begin{nameofenvironment}

\end{nameofenvironment}<++>
```

and puts the cursor in the body of the environment. You can leave the environment easily by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is there any shortkey that also autocomplete the `nameofenviron` to `nameofenvironment`?

Comment: Does not work for Neovim without configuration. At least it should be pointed out what should be configured for the shortcut `F5` to work.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

All of the solutions above close an environment for you after you have typed `\begin{<environment name>}...` but I prefer to just type the name of the environment and then have `vim` fill in the `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}` tags for me. To do this I have the following lines in `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim`:

```
" put \begin{} \end{} tags tags around the current word
map  <C-B>      YpkI\begin{<ESC>A}<ESC>jI\end{<ESC>A}<esc>kA
map! <C-B> <ESC>YpkI\begin{<ESC>A}<ESC>jI\end{<ESC>A}<esc>kA
```

This allows me to type a word at the start of a line, such as `align`, `itemize`, `theorem`, ... then control-B changes it into the mark-up for the environment. For example, if I type `align*` followed by control-B then vim translates this into:

```
\begin{align*}
\end{align*}
```

A useful feature of my macro is that it preserves indentation of the environment name.

**EDIT** As pointed out is the comments, this is a standard part of vim-latex.

Comment: cmhughes' answer describes the same function as this, which is built into vim-latex

Comment: @DaiBowen Thanks. I missed this. I won't delete the post as it provides the details of one way to do this without using vim-latex, which I at least don't use.

Answer (score 1):

You search for the [closeb](https://github.com/vim-scripts/closeb) plugin.
It does exactly what you describe.

If you enable it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> in insert mode,
it closes the current environment.

Answer (score 0):

put in your vimrc:

```
inoremap \end <><Esc>?begin<Enter>Vy/<><Enter>pfbcwend<Esc>kddo
```

How it works:
innoremap create a mapping keys in insert mode when you insert \end.
put a "<>" string, find(/) the word "begin" and copy the entire line (Vy), then back to the "<>" (\<>) and paste the line (p), find the first b in the line and change the word (cw) for "end" after that delete the "<>" string and put in insert mode.

So:
The text must be like that:

```
\begin{something}
some texot o comands
```

In diferents lines.
It must work.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the following incantation

```
map! <C-A> <ESC>"ayy"aPi\begin{<ESC>Ea}<ESC><CR>i\end{<ESC>Ea}<ESC>O
```

then, using A while in insert mode, the line

```
abc
```

turns into

```
\begin{abc}

\end{abc}
```

with the cursor in between (and still in insert mode).

Comment: The characters got interpreted and not printed (:-):

Comment: :map! <C-A> <ESC>"ayy"aPi\begin{<ESC>Ea}<ESC><CR>i\end{<ESC>Ea}<ESC>O