# shortcut for inserting matching endsomething in Windows

Tags: auto-completion

I would like to automatically inserting closing `environments` In MiKTeX-TeXWorks. And i have found [Shortcut for inserting matching \end{something} in VIM](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62182/shortcut-for-inserting-matching-endsomething-in-vim). Any other same options are available in Windows?

Comment: Well, [Vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) is available for Windows ...

Comment: You may try external integrated development environment called `TeXStudio`. It comes with auto-completion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Texworks, type `\beg` and <kbd>TAB</kbd>, you will get `\begin{`. Then type `doc` as in `\begin{doc` and again press <kbd>TAB</kbd> you will get

```
\begin{document}



\end{document}
```

with cursor in between.

Then type, say, `\beg` and <kbd>TAB</kbd> to get `\begin{` and type `ite` (`\begin{ite`) press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to get

```
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}•

\end{document}
```

There are many other short cuts that are defined in files like `tw-latex.txt`. To find these, go to `Help` → `Settings and Resources`. You will get this window:

[image]

Click on the link and the folder `C:\Users\HK\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\TeXworks\0.4` opens (HK may be different for you). Get inside the `completion` folder where you will find four files → `tw-basix.txt`, `tw-beamer.txt`, `tw-context.txt` and `tw-latex.txt`. You need `tw-latex.txt` where these shortcults can be found.

[image]

Foe example, type `bsubeq` and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> and see yourself.

---

In winedt, type

```
\begin{document}}   %%<--- extra brace
```

to get

```
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

or to close the environment that is open, type

```
\end{{
```

In winedt, to find short cuts, do something like this:

Go to `Options` → `Options Interface`, then press `Main Menu` once. Press the arrow head as shown and you will find shortcuts, click on shortcuts. Now all shortcuts are copied to clip board. Open a new file and paste.

[image]

Comment: Also in TeXworks: `bd` and then tab twice for `document`, `bi` for `itemize`, `bt` for `tabular`, `table` etc., `bf` for `frame`, `figure` etc., `beq` for `equation`. There are a lot more as well.

Comment: The complete list can be found in the completion files, so you can also define your own there. In TeXworks, go to Help --> Settings and Resources to find out where the resources folder is. Within that folder there is a `completion` subfolder which contains the text files with the completion patterns. See also https://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/CodeCompletion